# PHP array sending React Native Fetch

Tags: php, react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

I am new to React-Native and PHP, I am trying to send an array from PHP to REACT-NATIVE , the result is [object object] like nothing is receive for PHP ,the problem is the data can't display in the screen , the function of PHP it works well I test with the postman and everything was perfect but in the front nope , my code like this :

```
export class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    data: []
  };

componentWillMount() {
  alert(this.fetchData());
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/APP/Chauffeur/Backendapp/api/Traitement/AffichageStation.php");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.results });
  };

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
         data={this.state.data}
         keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
         renderItem={({ item }) =>
           <Text>
             {`${item.name.nom} ${item.name.adresse}`}
           </Text>}
       />
     </View>
   );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   marginTop: 15,
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: "center",
   alignItems: "center",
   backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
 }
});
/*const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 9,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#CAD9E5",
  },
  go:{
    marginTop: 90,
    position:"absolute",
    color:"red"
  }
});*/

export default Home;
```

The function chau

```php
<?php

$query = 'SELECT  A.idCH, A.idC, A.createdAt , S.nomStation as nom , S.adresse as adresse , C.quantite as quantite
    FROM Affectation A
    INNER JOIN Commande C ON A.idC=C.id
    INNER JOIN station S ON S.id=C.idS
    WHERE idCH=:idCH
         ORDER BY A.createdAt DESC';

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':idCH', $this->idCH);

// Execute query
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $stmt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($stmt as $key => $value) {
        return json_encode($stmt);
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
session_start();
include_once "../../config/Database.php";
include_once "../../models/Affectation.php";
$Database = new Database();
$db = $Database->connect();
$Affectation = new Affectation($db);

$Affectation->idCH = '105';
$results = $Affectation->chau();

echo $results;

?>
```

Comment: try to use JSON.stringify(this.state.data) so you can better understand what the data from backend.

Comment: where i use it ,  or i put it ? because i tried it and it didn't work

Comment: put console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.data)) in between render and return.

Comment: the return is [] , empty array

Answer (score 0):

With a `return` statement inside a `foreach` loop you will return at best just the first result.

Just `json_encode` the entire result set and return like this:

```
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    return json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
//    foreach ($stmt as $key => $value) {
//       return json_encode($stmt);
//    }
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

I just noticed you were returning `$stmt` not `$value` so you are indeed returning the entire result set. If you're just getting an empty array it suggests your query is not returning any results

Comment: the result of the query is always the correct answer ```json [
    {
        "idCH": "105",
        "idC": "15",
        "createdAt": "2019-07-05 15:11:04",
        "nom": "Station Service El Mouradia",
        "adresse": "Avenue Souidani Boudjemaa, El Mouradia",
        "quantite": "8000"
    },
    {
        "idCH": "105",
        "idC": "14",
        "createdAt": "2019-07-05 15:06:36",
        "nom": "Station Naftal Cheraga",
        "adresse": "Rue Higgoun Smail ,Mohamed Belouizdad 16000",
        "quantite": "5000"
    }
]```

Comment: i try what i have suggest but always the same result